# properties of p-wave superconductors in a self consistent calculation

Tags: superconductivity, quantum-hall-effect, anyons

2D p+ip superconductors have zero energy mid-gap modes localized at the boundaries as well as in the vortex cores as pointed out in several places such as [Read, Green](http://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.61.10267) and [Ivanov](http://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.86.268). The modes result in non-Abelian statistics and a non-trivial counting for the vortex excitations.

All these calculations, as far as I can understand, use a BdG equation to arrive at the above mentioned results. Is it clear that the mid-gap states and vortex structure predicted by BdG equation will be self-consistent ?

ie For a 4-fermion interaction Hamiltonian that results in a p-wave order parameter, will a self consistent calculation for the structure of a vortex give us the same properties that BdG equation gives ?

Thanks !